# Sorting By Excel Headers in MATLAB (High Level I/O)

Tags: matlab, sorting, if-statement, io, data-extraction

Alright, so I feel like this should be a pretty simple problem, but I'm already struggling with it. Which is bad since I have a test next week and I barely understand half the stuff we need to know. that, however, is besides the point. What I need to do is write a function that takes in an Excel file and a Header (which will be a string we input). It then finds the Header in the file and sorts it (in alphabetical order if the column consists of characters or ascending if it has numbers).

Input:

[image: Where is show the 44 Con thing, should be a 31]

Test Case:

```
 scores = sortByHeader(x, 'Opponent');
   scores => 'Opponent'              'Tech Points'    'Opponent Points'
            'Clemson'               [         30]    [             27]
            'Clemson'               [         39]    [             34]
            'Duke'                  [         49]    [             10]
            'Florida State'         [         49]    [             44]
            'Georgia'               [         24]    [             30]
            'Iowa'                  [         14]    [             24]
            'Jacksonville State'    [         37]    [             17]
            'Miami'                 [         17]    [             33]
            'Mississippi State'     [         42]    [             31]
            'North Carolina'        [         24]    [              7]
            'Vanderbilt'            [         56]    [             31]
            'Virginia'              [         34]    [              9]
            'Virginia Tech'         [         28]    [             23]
            'Wake Forest'           [         30]    [             27]
```

I am mostly having trouble figuring out how to identify the header in the problem. So far I Have:

```
  function[scores] = sortByHeader(File, Name)

    [num, txt, raw] = xlsread(File); %// Reads in the file

%// Gives me the dimensions of the file

    [r,c] = size(raw); 
 %// I want to look through all of the columns until I find the header I need  

    for i = 1:c 
%// I'm attempting to search through the file here

       if strcmp(raw(1, i), Name) 

%// Here's my issue. When it finds the name, I am not sure what to do with it then
           Name_Column = 1; 
       end
%// I tried to mask it, but this doesn't actually work.

    raw(Name_Column) = raw; 

%// How I plan to sort everything once I find it. Though I believe I need to adjust this slightly to solely account for the 'Name' Column.

    scores = sort(raw, 'ascend');
```

I mostly need tips at this point. I should probably work on figuring this stuff out on my own, but that's easier said than done. Note: The headers will not always be in the same place and there can be any number of rows or columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conveniently, the headers will always be in the first row of the variable 'raw' as you have defined above.

```
headerMatch = strcmp(raw, Name);
whichColumn = find(headerMatch(1,:));
```

This will return a logical array headerMatch with a 1 in the location of a match to your string, Name, and whichColumn will return the column number, since we're only looking in the first row.

Then it's a matter of pulling out the column you identified with those commands and sorting it, which is where you struggled before.  There are a couple of ways to address cell arrays and it can seem inconsistent, but it comes down to what you want as the output. If you want a cell array that is a sub-section of your current array back, use parenthesis like you use for matrix addressing.  If you are trying to get at the values inside the cells that you are addressing, use curly braces.  See the difference in how you pull out a cell array of strings or the values to make a vector in the two sort calls below.  The sort command is a little different for a cell array of strings vs a vector of numbers so that's why there are two different calls with two different argument formats.  Just have to check which one you're dealing with first, then pass to the appropriate sort function.

```
if ischar(raw{2, whichColumn}) % ischar checks if the first cell we want to sort has numbers or letters in it

    sortedColumn = sort(raw(2:end, whichColumn)); % Sort a cell array of strings

else 

    sortedColumn = sort(vertcat(raw{2:end, whichColumn}), 'ascend'); % Sort a vector of numbers

end
```

Edit:  To return the entirety of the spreadsheet data (without headers) sorted by a given column, specified by the header name, pull out the column index as above (the whichColumn variable).  Then use the 'sortrows' command to sort the cell array of spreadsheet data by that column.

```
sortedMatrix = sortrows(raw(2:end, :), whichColumn);
```

Comment: I figured it wasn't too difficult to do. How would I index that sortedColumn into the initial columns though? I tried to index it in, but that didn't work. I'm going to try a mask to see if that helps. Thank you by the way :)

Comment: You mean returning the imported matrix with the specified column sorted?

Comment: Yeah. I need the rows to match-up with the correct variable. You can see the final output as my test case. I think I might need to convert it from a cell type or something. I'm playing with it.

Comment: Oh, that's even easier than what I had done.  You'll want the 'sortrows' command.  Feed it the data with the headers stripped and which column to sort by and it'll handle the rest.  See edit above.

Comment: I just need a masterlist of all the commands MATLAB has. That would make life ten times easier.

Comment: Finding the right command is 90% of the battle!  Frustrating, but that's what practice is for.

Comment: Nevermind. I asked a silly question.
I appreciate the help :) and the explanations. Makes life ten times easier